# Connecting IBM iSeries to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-midrange

We are trying to connect a process within our AS400 to deliver information to a database that is in SQL Server 2016. We have an Apache Kafka server running and ready. What is the best way to connect the i Series to SQL Server using Apache Kafka? in such a way that an RPGLE program can deliver a message subscribed to a specific topic in Kafka.

Should we install something additional? are there open source options?

What should we configure?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this should probably be closed...

But, I'll throw the following out here....

There's various ways for RPG to interact with REST services

- open source [HTTP API](https://www.scottklement.com/httpapi/)
- IBM's own [Integrated Web Services (IWS) client](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/integrated-web-services-ibm-i-web-services-made-easy)
- [Db2 built in](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=overview-httppostblob-httppostclob-scalar-functions) functionality
- various commercial libraries ([GETURI](https://www.bvstools.com/geturi.html) for example)

Rather than interact directly from the producing RPGLE program, it's likely a better idea to have the RPG drop a message on a queue and have some background process send it out.

That background process could be all RPG, all Java, or RPG using Java classes.

[JTOpen, aka JT400,](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/)is the opensource version of the IBM i Toolbox for Java.

If for instance you wanted an all Java process to read from the queue and send a message.

You can even throw Apache Camel into the mix since it supports both a JT400 and Kalfka connector.  Here's an [example repo](https://github.com/IBM/ibmi-oss-examples/tree/master/camel) of showing Camel running on the IBM i reading from a data queue and sending to Kalfka.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to this old topic in case it could be relevant for anybody. All of the excellent options Charles mentioned above could be a good fit for streaming IBM i events to Kafka topic, however all of them would require custom development and direct IBM i -> Kafka API connectivity.

Our company, Infoview Systems, developed a [connector](https://www.infoviewsystems.com/as400-kafka-connector) that listens for IBM i Data Queue messages and sends them to Kafka topics in near real time with no custom development required. IBM i events (for example database changes or business events) could be captured and sent to Data Queues locally in native IBM i structure format, then Kafka Connector processes, parses, translates to JSON / AVRO / ... and sends to Kafka topic.